# Simple Client - Server scripts don't work, Timeout error 10060 when attempting to connect

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, client-server

I've looked at many similar questions yet I can't figure out why connections are never established, they simply timeout. I've seen some questions where it's suggested a firewall (windows firewall) issue could be blocking me but I'm not so sure, I've tried disabling the firewall on both machines but the problem persists. There are also python rules which allows incoming and outgoing connections on both machines.

I've checked my router settings but I can't find anything there to suggest port forwarding is disabled etc.

I keep one of my devices on my home network and the other on my mobile data hotspot to simulate devices on separate networks. I've swapped around these devices.

I've used wireshark to inspect packets, I can see packets leaving on either network but never being received.

client.py

```
import socket

HOST, PORT = SERVERS-EXTERNAL-IP, 65000 #Tried a variety of ports
data = "Hello very cool message"

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
    # Connect to server and send data
    sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
    sock.sendall(bytes(data + "\n", "utf-8"))


print(f"Sent:     {data}")
```

server.py

```
import socket

PORT = 65000
HOST = socket.gethostname() #Tried other things like '', ''localhost' etc
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind((HOST, PORT))
sock.listen(5)


print("Listening")
c, addr = sock.accept()
print("Accepted")
data = c.recv(1024)

sock.close()
```

client.py result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 15, in <module>
    sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

server.py result:

```
Listening
```

Any suggestions as to why I'm facing this issue?

Comment: *"I can't find anything there to suggest port forwarding is disabled"* - this is a strange information. Port forwarding needs to be explicitly configured in the router. There is no port forwarding by default. This sounds like you did not configure any port forwarding but expect it to be magically there.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich How do other applications communicate then over the internet without having had access to my router settings? E.g. I've setup an SSH server before which I've been able to access externally on a specific port, but didn't need to configure any type of port forwarding myself.

Comment: It is unclear for me what you actually did. But if you have setup a SSH server __inside a local network behind a NAT router__ you would need to have port forwarding to allow access from inside. If you have setup the SSH server on some external VPS then you would not need port forwarding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I managed to get it working. Port forwarding was NOT setup, contrary to what I believed before.

To resolve this I created a static local IP address for my server, and a port forward rule in my router settings to direct a specific port to the static IP for the server. The following site was quite useful:

https://portforward.com

Also thanks to @SteffenUllrich for directing me in the right way.